# What does the percentage symbol (%) mean?

Tags: java

I ran into some code containing the `%` symbol inside the array argument.

What does it mean and how does it work?

**Example:**

```
String[] name = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

System.out.println(name[4 % name.length]);
System.out.println(name[7 % name.length]);
System.out.println(name[50 % name.length]);
```

**Output:**

```
a
d
c
```

Comment: That is the modulo operator. It calculates the remainder of an integer division

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: [Remainder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3), not modulo. It would handle negative numbers differently if it were modulo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's the [remainder operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3), it gives the remainder of integer division. For instance, `3 % 2` is `1` because the remainder of `3 / 2` is `1`.

It's being used there to keep a value in range: If `name.length` is less than 4, 7, or 50, the result of `% name.length` on those values is a value that's in the range `0` to `name.length - 1`.

So that code picks entries from the array reliably, even when the numbers (4, 7, or 50) are out of range. `4 % 4` is `0`, `7 % 4` is `3`, `50 % 4` is `2`. All of those are valid array indexes for `name`.

Complete example ([live copy](http://ideone.com/JEGhlu)):

```
class Example
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String[] name = { "a" , "b" , "c" , "d"};
        int n;
        n = 4 % name.length;
        System.out.println(" 4 % 4 is " + n + ": " + name[n]);
        n = 7 % name.length;
        System.out.println(" 7 % 4 is " + n + ": " + name[n]);
        n = 50 % name.length;
        System.out.println("50 % 4 is " + n + ": " + name[n]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 4 % 4 is 0: a
 7 % 4 is 3: d
50 % 4 is 2: c
```

Comment: So, it means that, it'll not throw any errors but result won't be as expected, right?

Comment: @TheAlpha: Depends on what the expected result is. :-) Using `%` to keep values in range is **very** common, and gives the expected result if you're expecting to keep it in range. You mostly see it with indexes where you want to loop around: `index = (index + 1) % size`

Comment: @Mr.Blue: Glad that helped. BTW, the `()` around `4`, `7`, and `50` in the quoted don't do anything. In general, the grouping operator (`()`) around a *single value* serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: this is the *modulo*, or to be precise the *remainder* operator.

This has nothing to do with arrays per se. It is just a numerical computation on the value that gets used to compute the array index.